# Get total number of files inside a tar.gz file using php

Tags: php, zip, tar, phar, gzip

I'm noob with php, but in a project I want to count the number of files that have a tar.gz, I know how to count files for a zip, but my question is: can I (with a php function) count how many files there are in a tar.gz file.?

With php I can count the number of files inside a zip file with a code like this

```
$zip = new ZipArchive(); 
if($zip->open("/path/to/the/zip")===true)
{
    print $zip->numFiles;
}
else
{
    print "cant open zip file";
}
```

but for tgz files can I do some similar (without use exec function)?

thanks :)

---

Thanks to Kkinsey I have an answer (with a few modification of his code). the final code will be

```
<?php

$archive = new PharData('/route/to/file.tar.gz');
$i=0;
foreach($archive as $file) 
{
    $i+=1;
}
print $i;
?>
```

thank you @Kkinsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PharData](http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php):

```
// Example: list files
$archive = new PharData('/some/file.tar.gz');
foreach($archive as $file) {
        echo "$file\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks :D it's work perfectly (with a few modification)

Comment: You're welcome!  Note that in later versions of PHP (I tried 5.7), the PharData object is iterable, so you can probably just use count($archive) instead of looping with a counter.